# What is the formal mode to say Hello in an mail?

Tags: british-english, formal-language

With an example:

I want to write the mail an important person, with this form

---

Hello Satoshi.

*Some text*

Regards.

Vincent.

---

I want to say to the formal salute, or if I use the Hi/Hello don't is an error?

Comment: Use their title if appropriate: "Dear Lady Langley, ... Yours sincerely, vincenzopalazzo." Or "Dear Professor Pendle etc." Or "Dear Mr Satoshi, etc."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Salutations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salutation) in English are formulaic. That is, you cannot change your actual greeting very much from the greeting expected by the reader.

This means you will use the following very often: **Dear *honorific* *surname*,** though you may use **Dear *given name* *surname*,** if it is necessary to avoid confusion or it is desirable to avoid using the honorific. A title may also be used in place of the honorific.

Examples.

> Dear Dr Williams,
>
> Dear Elizabeth Johnson,
>
> Dear Ms Watson,
>
> Dear Mr Smith,
>
> Dear Professor Black,

And so on. Note the lack of punctuation at the end of abbreviated honorifics.  This is current British usage.